# Parsing articles from a xml file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to parse an xml file including several articles:

```
<root>
    <article id="0000001" published-at="2017-10-12" title="Trump Just Woke Up &amp; Viciously Attacked Puerto Ricans On Twitter Like A Cruel Old Man">
      <p>Donald Trump ran on many braggadocios and largely unrealistic campaign promises. One of <a href="http://www.cnn.com/2017/03/16/politics/trump-infrastructure/index.html" type="external">those promises</a> was to be the best, the hugest, the most competent
        infrastructure president the United States has ever seen. Trump was going to fix every infrastructure problem in the country and Make America Great Again in the process.</p>
      <p>That is, unless you’re a brown American. In that case, you’re on your own, even after a massive natural disaster like Hurricane Maria.</p>
      <p>Puerto Rico’s debt, which the Puerto Rican citizens not in government would have no responsibility for, has nothing to do with using federal emergency disaster funds to save the lives of American citizens there. The infrastructure is certainly a mess
        at this point after a Category 5 hurricane ripped through the island, and <a href="http://abcnews.go.com/US/16-percent-puerto-rico-power-weeks-hurricane-maria/story?id=50417366" type="external">84 percent</a> of Puerto Rican people are currently without
        electricity.</p>
      <p>Emergency efforts after Hurricanes Irma and Harvey reportedly went very well and Trump praised himself as well and even saw his disastrous approval ratings tick up slightly as a result. However, the insufficient response in Puerto Rico has nothing to
        do with Trump, in his mind, and can only be blamed on the people there who do not live in a red state and have no electoral college votes to offer the new president for 2020.</p>
      <p>They’re on their own.</p>
      <p>Twitter responded with sheer incredulity at Trump’s vicious attack on an already suffering people.</p> Featured image screengrab via
      <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4pMxaH5oxs&amp;t=57s" type="external">YouTube</a></p>
    </article>
    <article id="0000002" published-at="2017-10-11" title="Liberals wailing about gun control, but what about abortion?">
      Photo By Justin Sullivan/Getty Images
      <p>In response to Joyce Newman’s recent letter about a conversation about guns: According to the National Right to Life Organization, approximately 600,000 babies are murdered every year by Planned Parenthood with more than 52 million murdered since Roe
        v. Wade. This makes Planned Parenthood the biggest mass murderer in the history of the world. Is she willing to have a serious conversation about that? Where is her outrage over that?</p>
      <p>More people die every year from overdoses or auto accidents then from guns. More people die every year from obesity then from guns. Where is her outrage over those issues?</p>
      <p>The left’s obsession with gun “control” is just that, control. It has always been about Democrats wanting to control every aspect of your life. They support Planned Parenthood but go ballistic when a gun is used to kill someone. It’s the old game of
        “don’t pay any attention to what’s going on over there, but look what’s happening here.”</p>
    </article>
</root>
```

I was able to extract the article id and the title, but I didn't figure it out how can I extract the content with `<p></p>` tags.
I have tried with the following code:

```
for article in root.iter():
    p = article.find('p').text
```

I got this error :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Could someone help me to check how should I fix the code, and moreover, how can I extract them without `<a></a>` tags?

Comment: Please provide the XML content as text, not as a image.

Comment: I changed to the text now :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the module beautifulsoup?
If not I would highly recommend using it there you can use the function:

```
content = article.select('p')
for element in content:
    content.append(element.text)
    content.remove(element)
```

This should get you all the paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you! I was using element tree. However, when I used beautifulsoup for your code: `for content in soup.find_all('article'):
    content = article.select('p').text`. I got the error of "'list' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: Sorry when you use the .find function you get a list of all elements that are paragraphs. You need to go through the list and turn every element to a paragraph. I edited the code so that it will work.

Comment: thanks it seems working.. :) but do you know how can I not return <p></p> tags from the texts? as the tags are not what I wanted

Comment: Ohh yeah... I think you just have to create the list content before the for loop. Then the result should be without any <p>.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you use xml.etree.ElementTree, so try:

```py
for article in root.iter():
    pg = article.findall('p')
    if pg:
       p = pg[0]
```

or you can iterate to get all values.

Comment: thanks :) I tried your way but it only returned the first 'p' element.. but how can i iterate all the 'p' element if every article I have contains different numbers of 'p' elements?

Comment: I don't get what did you mean for the statement for pg? But I'd really like to know how it will work here :)

Answer (score 0):

Use that code it was working for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
article = your_file_text
article = BeautifulSoup(article, "html.parser")

content = []
for element in article.find_all('p'):
    element = element.text.strip()
    content.append(element)
```